# Is there a prefix for 'old'?

Tags: grammar, terminology, constructed-language

I am writing a sci-fi novel in which humanity has struggled to survive in colonies throughout the solar system after the Earth becomes uninhabitable. I am writing a passage about a main character's back story and want to make their parent a geologist. The issue is that I feel like there would be a difference to distinguish geologists who study the Earth and those that study the other planets. It seems pretty normal now that adding 'xeno' to anything in space makes it about space (i.e. xenobiologists study the biology of alien life, and xenogeologists would study the geology of other planets). Similarly, I have seen the usage of 'neo' for anything new.

**I am wanting to use a prefix to distinguish Earth based geology from geology work done on other planets and am wondering if there is a prefix used that indicates something is old.**

Comment: This is off-topic and should be asked on one of the language Stack Exchanges. But these types of prefixes are usually Latin or Greek adjectives. "Xeno" means "other/strange/alien", "neo" means "new", and you can just use Google Translate to find a fitting prefix for "old". "Archaios" actually seems to be the world for old that is used in words like archaic, archeology, archetype etc., so maybe "Archegeology" would do the trick.